# Replace .html to / on htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

I want to replace .html to /, but the code only remove the .html

Example:
**example.com/page.html** to **example.com/page/**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to simply add a `/` at the end of `/$1`.

So this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=302]
```

This will give you your desired URLs.

Complete working `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=302]
```